# How to solve algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I solve an algebraic equation with only two variables. I have tried  through graphical method but can't  get it correct.Here it is:
$$3x-y=2x+3y$$

Comment: It simplifies to $x=4y$

Comment: That is a graph of $y=\frac{1}{4}x$ so all pairs of $(x,y)$ on that line are solutions.

Comment: I'd be curious to know how you handled this graphically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the expression:
$$3x-y=2x+3y\implies 3y+y=3x-2x\implies 4y=x$$
Hence the solutoin of your equation are all the point of the graphic given by the $\color{red}{y=\frac x4}$

That is this:
$\hspace{6cm}$[image]

Answer (score 0):

An equation of this form denotes the intersection between two planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$, namely the set

$$S = \{ (x,y) \mid 3x - y = 2x + 3y \}$$

In general, the intersection between two planes can be the empty set (if the planes are parallel), a line or a plan (if the two planes coincide).

By looking at their normal vectors, we immediately see that the planes $z = 3x - y$ and $z = 2x +3$ do not coincide and are not parallel.

It is somewhat difficult to solve it graphically, as finding $S$ involves drawing the planes $z = 3x - y$ and $z = 2x + 3y$.

A better approach is to note that if $3x - y = 2x + 3y$, then $x = 4y$ and therefore $y = \frac{1}{4}x$. This is the equation defining $S$.

Comment: My bet is that the OP never learnt any 3D analytical geometry.

Comment: Well,I see it is possible to solve graphically,.but can it be solved using substitution method?

Comment: But that is what all the answers here explain.

Answer (score 0):

There are two unknowns but a single equation, so that the problem is (once) undeterminate.

You can set one of the variables to an arbitrary value, and solve for the other.

For instance, choose $y$ as the independent variable and draw

$$x=4y.$$